# Change audio Attributes with css only

Tags: css

I have an interesting issue that I can not seem to figure out. I am using a company to create a website for me and in their templates, they will allow me access to CSS but not to the HTML or Jquery. I need to figure out a way to change the muted too unmuted or be able to remove it.

```
<video style="height:100%;" loop="" muted="" autoplay="" poster="https://removed from code" playsinline="">
</video>
```

I can only use css to fix this, any ideas?

Comment: This is impossible. However, you being their client should ask this company to either do what you need directly, either give you access to the HTML + JS. You paid for this, it's yours.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<video id="myVideo" src="video.mp4" controls replay autoplay></video>
```